# SSRS ORA-01008 not all variables bound

Tags: reporting-services, visual-studio-2017

Using SSRS with VS 2017 I am receiving the ORA-01008 not all variables bound message when connecting to Oracle via the ole db connector.  The code works normally through sql developer.  Similar code worked fine in VS 2016 before we upgraded to vs 2017.  Any ideas what's causing this issue

Code:

select tr.id_number
  FROM rpt_transaction_view TR
  WHERE TR.unit_code=:pUnit

Error Message:

### TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server Report Designer

An error occurred while executing the query.
ORA-01008: not all variables bound
ORA-01008: not all variables bound

---

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

ORA-01008: not all variables bound
ORA-01008: not all variables bound (OraOLEDB)

---

BUTTONS:

### OK

Comment: This happen to me when I switched from "Oracle Database" to OLE DB. Having you tried using 'Oracle Database" instead?

Answer (score 0):

A little late BUT I think I found a solution (if you want to call it that). A little background, I've been working with SSRS since BIDS and have NEVER encountered this error before... until today. I have spent hours googling, trying to find what the solution is and NOTHING worked. 
Now, I build all my queries in Oracle SQL Developer, and noticed something different about the offending query - the "SELECT" was underlined, basically Oracle SQL Developer wanted to rewrite the query, so I let it. Now I had two parameters, we'll call them :p1 and :p2, each being used three times throughout the query. When the query was re-written (to something almost unreadable) it replaced the parameters with :b1, :b2, :b3, :b4, :b5 and :b6. All odd parameters (:b1, :b3 and :b5) were :p1 and the evens :p2.  I used a find and replace so I was back to only using the 2 parameters.  I replaced the dataset in my report with this query, ran it and voila error gone...

Why?  I have not the slightest idea.  It's not like this query was unique to other queries I've used.  I have over 400 oracle based reports and I've never had to do anything like this and this query wasn't as nearly as complicated as others I've written.  I have some queries that use the same parameters a half dozen times and no issue - just this one.

Anyways, thought I would share in case anyone else was 100% stumped as I was.